# solution of equation $x^n-y^m=2$

Tags: diophantine-equations

can anyone give me solution of $x^n-y^m=2$ where $x,y$ are positive integers and $m,n$ greater than or equal to $2$ except $(x,y,n,m)=(3,5,3,2)$ ?if this is only solution of given equation,then can anyone prove it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is Pillai's conjecture, e.g., on the integer solutions of
$$
x^n-y^m=c
$$
with $n,m\ge 2$ and $c\ge 1$. There should be only finitely many solutions, and very often only one - see [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/0908.4031), Conjecture $1.6$.
There is also an interesting paper by [Michael A. Bennett](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~bennett/B-CJM-Pillai.pdf), which shows some more results here. In fact, he proves that   $3^3-5^2=2$ is the only solution in positive integers for $c=2$, see Theorem $1.5$.